# PostGIS Column not found in geometry_columns table

Tags: postgis-2.0, srid, shp2pgsql

I've just loaded a bunch of shapefiles into postgis using psql2shp (from the command line). All of the shapefiles appeared to have been inserted correctly and the table I created is populated. But the points are projected in the wrong location. I specified the SRID when I imported them using the -s switch in psql:

```
for i in $(find . -type f -name "*.shp"); do shp2pgsql -I -s 3857 -a $i \ supermarkets_all  | psql --cluster 12/main osm;  done;
```

If I now check the SRID using `Find_SRID()` I get an error:
"ERROR:  find_srid() - could not find the corresponding SRID - is the geometry registered in the GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table?  Is there an uppercase/lowercase mismatch?
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function find_srid(character varying,character varying,character varying) line 17 at RAISE
SQL state: P0001"

I've also checked that the geometry_columns view contains my geometry column - which it does. However, the table that it relates to is preceded by square brackets - I'm not sure if this is relevant? [image]

Is there anyway to fix the geometry - or do I just need to re-import all of the data and try again?

Answer (score 1):

1. May be there could also be an issue with your table names based on escaping the space before `\ supermarket` and escaped after `$i`, command
   `shp2pgsql -I -s 3857 -a $i \ supermarkets_all`
   in your script.  IMO it is directly translated into the SQL code using double quotes around the table name. Your provided table shows, all entries starting with "[...]supermaket*" have a `SRID 0`.  May be this is not coded/ escaped within the `Find_SRID()` stored procedure. I prefer to use proper SQL92 conform identifiers for table and column names.
2. You could check the column type directly in the table with `\d+ " superkarket` (`psql` command line tool) to find out, if there is a misfit between the table `geometry_columns` entries and the table definition it self. There should appear something like `column_name  geometry(TYPE, EPSG)` corresponding to the geometry columns entry.
3. If not I think (but I'm not sure) you can touch the geometry columns directly with

   `ALTER NAME column TYPE GEOMETRY('POINT', EPSG)`

Comment: thanks, yep I hadn't noticed that my tables all had a space before the actual name. The entries in geometry_columns table and the table name itself do match though. I've even renamed tables to remove the space. But still no joy. I queried the table from the command line as you suggested and the geometry column name from my table (geom) matches the entry in the geometry_columns table. So not really sure what else has gone wrong here...

Comment: But the SRID in your provided table is ZERO, which is not a valid EPSG.  I think you alter the geometry column in your teble ensemble.

Comment: Hi @huckfinn - yes its true for some tables - SRID is ZERO, BUT not for the table I refer to here "supermarkets_all". SRID is 3857 (see row 11 of the table above in my screenshot)...